# How can i call a new view to show results after doing a search on "search bar"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm doing a Tab Bar Application and I have a view with a Search Bar and I want to call a new view to show the results on a tableview when the user clicks on the search button of the ipod/iphone keyboard.

Here you got a few [mock-ups](http://twitpic.com/3bp6hg)  to clarify the idea:

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `UISearchBar` class has a delegate class, `UISearchBarDelegate`. Its method `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`: is called when a user clicks the search button on the keyboard. Within this delegate method, you can push your new view onto the navigation stack or use whatever display logic you want.

```
-(void) loadView{
   // set up your view ...

   // set up your search bar
   UISearchBar *searchBar = [[[UISearchBar alloc] init] autorelease];
   [searchBar setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
   //push your view controller onto the nav stack or whatever
}
```